# sort order import in react using cra

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I am trying to update my project's configuration to sort the import order. I'm using `create-react-app`, and have been following the instructions in this [article](https://dev.to/otamnitram/sorting-your-imports-correctly-in-react-213m). Here's what I've done so far:

1. Run `yarn add eslint-plugin-import -D`.
2. Added a .eslintrc.js in src folder of my application.
3. Added the following configuration as mentioned in the article:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: "react-app",
  plugins: ["eslint-plugin-import"],
  "import/order": [
    "error",
    {
      groups: ["builtin", "external", "internal"],
      pathGroups: [
        {
          pattern: "react",
          group: "external",
          position: "before",
        },
      ],
      pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes: ["react"],
      "newlines-between": "always",
      alphabetize: {
        order: "asc",
        caseInsensitive: true,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

I've written the following sample component and changed the order of `import` statements to check if this is working, but when I save the order is not being updated:

Sample.js

```
import { PropTypes } from "prop-types";
import React from "react";

const Sample = () => <div>Hello</div>;

export default Sample;
```

Expected after saving

Sample.js

```
import React from "react";

import { PropTypes } from "prop-types";

const Sample = () => <div>Hello</div>;

export default Sample;
```

I also tried [`simple-import-sort`](https://github.com/lydell/eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort), but I don't know how to configure it. How can I configure my project so that `import` statements are automatically kept in order?

Comment: Another approach is to use alt+shift+o to organize imports in VSCode. It's built into the editor, though you'd have to remember to run it for files.

Comment: For mac whats the shortcut, but will it be specific as per the config how we want. I have tried adding "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": true
    }, but as per react. Import React from 'react' should be the first one. So any way to do this. Also everyone needs to add this in vscode, so it will be specific to every workspace. But i am trying to put this config only for this project. Is that doable

Comment: You can set up workspace specific settings in VSCode, but yeah, I was talking about the organizeImports feature. My personal opinion is that I've been working with React for 2+ years and I've never heard of a convention to make sure that React is imported first. Plus in new versions of React, it doesn't even need to be imported wholesale anymore as part of the [new jsx transform feature](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/10/20/react-v17.html#new-jsx-transform). If you are naming your files with `.jsx` or `.tsx`, it's pretty obvious it's React.

Comment: Points what you have mentioned are valid, but most of the projects i have seen first they start with the react then the polyfills then the absolute , relative path and remaining imports. So as per the article i feel its a better way. or simple import sort is also better, but i am stuck on saving even though added the configuration its not re ordering. If any idea on it let me know it will be helpful. Have seen most of the people uses simple import sort as it supports import {b,a,c} from 'Constants' to import {a,b,c} from 'Constants'. If any idea or thought do let me know as i am newbie to this

Comment: @ZacharyHaber Also if you find this useful, please do vote for it so for newbie's like me it will be helpful. Also please add if in case i have missed anything on the question.

Answer (score 0):

in `pathGroups` change react to be `built`, not `external`:

```
"pathGroups": [
                {
                  "group": "builtin",
                  "pattern": "react",
                  "position": "before"
                },
                {
                  "group": "external",
                  "pattern": "@/**",
                  "position": "before"
                }]
```